# Finding and singling out pattern from text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm parsing a CSV file into JSON and want to single out some stuff, mainly because I want to use it to draw a graph. The output looks like this

Parser Output:

`{ "data": [ { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "CNRS", "Overall": "22,6", "1996": "18,4", "1997": "18,6", "1998": "18,5", "1999": "17,3", "2000": "17,6", "2001": "18,6", "2002": "18,3", "2003": "17,5", "2004": "18,9", "2005": "20,2", "2006": "21,1", "2007": "22,1", "2008": "21,3", "2009": "22,9", "2010": "23,4", "2011": "25,3", "2012": "24,5", "2013": "29,3", "2014": "31,7" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "DACH - Austria, Germany and Switzerland", "Overall": "16,9", "1996": "13,3", "1997": "13,4", "1998": "13,6", "1999": "14,1", "2000": 14, "2001": "14,8", "2002": "15,1", "2003": "14,9", "2004": "15,5", "2005": "15,5", "2006": "15,8", "2007": "16,2", "2008": "16,1", "2009": "16,4", "2010": "17,6", "2011": "18,6", "2012": "18,4", "2013": "21,7", "2014": "25,1" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Europe", "Overall": "13,5", "1996": "11,2", "1997": "11,2", "1998": "11,3", "1999": "11,5", "2000": "11,5", "2001": "12,2", "2002": "12,3", "2003": "12,2", "2004": "12,5", "2005": "12,6", "2006": "12,8", "2007": 13, "2008": "12,6", "2009": "12,8", "2010": "13,4", "2011": "14,1", "2012": "13,7", "2013": "16,5", "2014": "21,4" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "J. Stefan Institute", "Overall": "13,3", "1996": "6,5", "1997": 8, "1998": "8,9", "1999": "9,7", "2000": 8, "2001": "10,6", "2002": 7, "2003": "8,2", "2004": 12, "2005": "9,5", "2006": "10,6", "2007": "13,4", "2008": "11,9", "2009": "12,8", "2010": "14,9", "2011": "15,5", "2012": "15,2", "2013": "19,7", "2014": "25,6" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Max Planck Society", "Overall": "30,3", "1996": "25,9", "1997": 24, "1998": "24,3", "1999": 25, "2000": "25,6", "2001": 27, "2002": "26,2", "2003": "27,6", "2004": "27,8", "2005": "27,8", "2006": "28,1", "2007": "29,4", "2008": "29,2", "2009": "30,9", "2010": "32,4", "2011": "33,2", "2012": "34,8", "2013": "39,8", "2014": "38,9" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "National Institute of Biology Ljubljana", "Overall": "17,7", "1996": 4, "1997": "13,3", "1998": 20, "1999": "13,3", "2000": "9,1", "2001": 15, "2002": "15,6", "2003": "20,8", "2004": "18,2", "2005": "14,7", "2006": "14,3", "2007": 18, "2008": "19,7", "2009": 20, "2010": "21,1", "2011": "16,7", "2012": "18,2", "2013": 19, "2014": "24,1" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "National Institute of Chemistry Ljubljana", "Overall": "21,5", "1996": "8,8", "1997": "4,1", "1998": "9,9", "1999": 15, "2000": "15,7", "2001": "21,4", "2002": "15,3", "2003": "18,4", "2004": "16,2", "2005": "20,4", "2006": "19,4", "2007": "30,8", "2008": "18,1", "2009": "19,4", "2010": "31,8", "2011": "23,1", "2012": "24,9", "2013": "29,3", "2014": 36 }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Scientific Research Centre of the Slovenian Academy of Sciences and Arts", "Overall": "5,9", "1996": 0, "1997": 0, "1998": 0, "1999": 0, "2000": 0, "2001": "NA", "2002": 0, "2003": 0, "2004": "14,3", "2005": "4,5", "2006": 0, "2007": 0, "2008": 0, "2009": "7,8", "2010": "2,4", "2011": "6,8", "2012": "4,8", "2013": 0, "2014": 30 }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Slovenia", "Overall": "10,7", "1996": "5,8", "1997": "5,7", "1998": "5,7", "1999": "6,8", "2000": "5,5", "2001": "6,5", "2002": "6,8", "2003": "7,6", "2004": "7,8", "2005": "8,5", "2006": "9,3", "2007": "10,7", "2008": "9,6", "2009": "9,7", "2010": "10,8", "2011": "11,8", "2012": "12,3", "2013": "15,4", "2014": "20,4" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "United States", "Overall": "18,3", "1996": "17,3", "1997": "17,5", "1998": "17,7", "1999": "17,7", "2000": "17,8", "2001": "18,9", "2002": "18,5", "2003": "17,7", "2004": "17,7", "2005": "17,3", "2006": "17,3", "2007": "17,6", "2008": "17,3", "2009": "17,4", "2010": "17,7", "2011": "18,4", "2012": "17,8", "2013": "20,2", "2014": 24 }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Universitat Stuttgart", "Overall": "12,9", "1996": "12,7", "1997": "10,5", "1998": "14,2", "1999": "13,8", "2000": "10,6", "2001": "11,5", "2002": "12,6", "2003": "10,3", "2004": "11,8", "2005": "9,7", "2006": "11,9", "2007": "11,2", "2008": "11,8", "2009": "11,9", "2010": "11,4", "2011": "13,7", "2012": "11,8", "2013": "16,4", "2014": "23,6" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "University of Ljubljana", "Overall": "10,9", "1996": "6,2", "1997": "6,1", "1998": "6,1", "1999": "7,1", "2000": 5, "2001": 6, "2002": "6,8", "2003": "8,9", "2004": "7,8", "2005": "8,8", "2006": "10,1", "2007": "11,3", "2008": "10,6", "2009": "10,2", "2010": "10,9", "2011": "12,1", "2012": "13,2", "2013": "14,6", "2014": "20,2" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "University of Maribor", "Overall": "9,5", "1996": "4,8", "1997": "3,6", "1998": "3,9", "1999": "1,9", "2000": "2,4", "2001": "2,4", "2002": "6,5", "2003": "4,5", "2004": "6,4", "2005": "8,8", "2006": "8,1", "2007": "9,4", "2008": 10, "2009": "8,5", "2010": "7,7", "2011": "9,9", "2012": 13, "2013": "15,9", "2014": "19,6" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "University of Nova Gorica", "Overall": "18,2", "1996": "NA", "1997": "NA", "1998": "NA", "1999": "8,3", "2000": 0, "2001": "4,2", "2002": 4, "2003": 10, "2004": "9,3", "2005": "12,3", "2006": 22, "2007": "25,2", "2008": "17,5", "2009": "12,2", "2010": "15,3", "2011": "15,9", "2012": "18,3", "2013": "25,6", "2014": "27,5" } ], "errors": [], "meta": { "delimiter": ";", "linebreak": "\r\n", "aborted": false, "truncated": false, "fields": [ "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)", "Overall", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014" ] } }`

is there a way to search for numbers after a certain year, like 1996: 18,4 (I only want to get 18,4 on a variable)? The numbers are all on a single decimal and never go higher than 100 (they're %).
I thought I'd make a for loops that finds the 1996: and then prints out a certain lenght of characters after it. I am now pretty sure this is not the right way to do this :)

So what I want to do is get data for every single year on a separate array, so then I can easily acces it and use it as x for my graph.

The site so far:

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    if ( !(evt.target && evt.target.files && evt.target.files[0]) ) {
        return;
    }    
    Papa.parse(evt.target.files[0], {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        complete: function (results) {
            debugDataset(results);
            renderDataset(results);
        }
    });
}

function debugDataset(dataset) {
    var formatted = JSON.stringify(dataset, null, 2);
    $("<div class='parse'></div>").text(formatted).appendTo(".graphcontainer");
}

function renderDataset(dataset) {
    // render code here...
}

$(function () {
    $("#csv-file").change(handleFileSelect);
});
```

```css
.graphcontainer {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    
    margin:auto;
}

.buttoncontainer {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:5px;
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

.parse {
    width:500px;
    height:480px;
    
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>csv testing</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/PapaParse/papaparse.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="graphcontainer">Parser Output:</div>
        <div class="buttoncontainer">
        <input type="file" id="csv-file" name="files"/>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

the CSV file I'm working with:(http://topdeckandwreck.com/excel%20graphs/)

thanks for the help

edited with complete output data

Comment: That's not CSV, looks more like JSON, and it can be easily sorted and filtered.

Comment: Yeah, the code so far takes a CSV file and parses it in JSON then displays it on a DIV. Sry about not being more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know.  It's not too bad.  It's a little complicated, but parsing out the data via the keys can be done through javascript.  It would, of course, be more maintainable to format the data serverside after it's grabbed from whatever database it's stored in, but this solution can work.

```js
var raw_data = { "data": [ { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "CNRS", "Overall": "22,6", "1996": "18,4", "1997": "18,6", "1998": "18,5", "1999": "17,3", "2000": "17,6", "2001": "18,6", "2002": "18,3", "2003": "17,5", "2004": "18,9", "2005": "20,2", "2006": "21,1", "2007": "22,1", "2008": "21,3", "2009": "22,9", "2010": "23,4", "2011": "25,3", "2012": "24,5", "2013": "29,3", "2014": "31,7" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "DACH - Austria, Germany and Switzerland", "Overall": "16,9", "1996": "13,3", "1997": "13,4", "1998": "13,6", "1999": "14,1", "2000": 14, "2001": "14,8", "2002": "15,1", "2003": "14,9", "2004": "15,5", "2005": "15,5", "2006": "15,8", "2007": "16,2", "2008": "16,1", "2009": "16,4", "2010": "17,6", "2011": "18,6", "2012": "18,4", "2013": "21,7", "2014": "25,1" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Europe", "Overall": "13,5", "1996": "11,2", "1997": "11,2", "1998": "11,3", "1999": "11,5", "2000": "11,5", "2001": "12,2", "2002": "12,3", "2003": "12,2", "2004": "12,5", "2005": "12,6", "2006": "12,8", "2007": 13, "2008": "12,6", "2009": "12,8", "2010": "13,4", "2011": "14,1", "2012": "13,7", "2013": "16,5", "2014": "21,4" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "J. Stefan Institute", "Overall": "13,3", "1996": "6,5", "1997": 8, "1998": "8,9", "1999": "9,7", "2000": 8, "2001": "10,6", "2002": 7, "2003": "8,2", "2004": 12, "2005": "9,5", "2006": "10,6", "2007": "13,4", "2008": "11,9", "2009": "12,8", "2010": "14,9", "2011": "15,5", "2012": "15,2", "2013": "19,7", "2014": "25,6" } ] };

// create the object to store the values.  If you know associative
// arrays, this is the same concept.  We're creating keys that store
// each of the values.  This way we can keep referencing the same 
// property (e.g. 1998) and append each value wherever it should go.
var formatted_data = {};

// loop over the raw data
for(var i in raw_data.data) {
  // here we are grabbing all the keys for this row. (e.g. 1996, 1997,
  // and even "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)")
  var keys = Object.keys(raw_data.data[i]);

  // loop over all the keys
  for(var k = 0, len = keys.length; k < len; k++) {
    // First check to see if our key (1996 or whatever) is already in
    // the formatted_data variable.  If it is, append to it.  If it
    // isn't, we need to create it.
    if(typeof formatted_data[keys[k]] !== "undefined") {
      // it exists!  Tack on the value now.
      formatted_data[keys[k]].push(raw_data.data[i][keys[k]]);
    } else {
      // it doesn't exist, create a new one and instantiate an array
      // with one entry: the value.
      formatted_data[keys[k]] = new Array(raw_data.data[i][keys[k]])
    }
  }
}

// output for debugging
console.log(formatted_data);
```

```html
<strong>See javascript console for output</strong>
```

Comment: So I've changed raw data input in the code after resolving the parser errors and now I get the arrays with the results I want (array[14]). Now my questions are the following: How do I target specific arrays the code outputs?

Comment: Also some of the values in the arrays are only numbers while most of the others have "" around them. Can you see a specific reason for this? I would also be very grateful if you could comment your code step by step so I know exactly what's going on. But so far this seems to be the working solution

Comment: Now that the data is in `formatted_data`, it's an object and all the dates are its properties.  `formatted_data` has the property `1998` which contains the array for that date.  Due to the names of the properties, you **can't reference it** like you would normal object properties (e.g. `className.propName`)  That's because it uses numbers.  You **can however reference** them like this: `formatted_data['1998']`.  To get the first one: `formatted_data['1998'][0]`.

Comment: My best guess for the issue with the quotes is that the exported data is escaping commas with double quotes.  That's typical with CSV exports.  Can't have rogue commas everywhere.  I'll edit my code to add commas and cast the values to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map and filter methods of JavaScript to isolate columns of data from your parsed JSON structure.

Here is an example of .map to get the third column of a 2-dimensional array:

```
// 2D array
var arr2d = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]];

// get the third column
var col3 = arr2d.map(
    function(value, index) {
        return value[2];  // 2 is index of third column
    }
);

// col3 is now [3, 6, 9]
```

In your case this should be the way to get all 1996 values returned in an array:

```
// provide your JSON in variable parserOutput

// get the column of year 1996
var col1996 = parserOutput.data.map(
    function(value, index) {
        return value["1996"];  // dot notation would be possible here, if key wasn't a number
    }
);

// col1996 is now ["18,4", "13,3", "11,2", "6,5"]
```

**UPDATE:**

Code snippet with your example data:

```js
// provide your JSON in variable parserOutput
var parserOutput = { 
  "data": [ 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "CNRS", "Overall": "22,6", "1996": "18,4", "1997": "18,6", "1998": "18,5", "1999": "17,3", "2000": "17,6", "2001": "18,6", "2002": "18,3", "2003": "17,5", "2004": "18,9", "2005": "20,2", "2006": "21,1", "2007": "22,1", "2008": "21,3", "2009": "22,9", "2010": "23,4", "2011": "25,3", "2012": "24,5", "2013": "29,3", "2014": "31,7" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "DACH - Austria, Germany and Switzerland", "Overall": "16,9", "1996": "13,3", "1997": "13,4", "1998": "13,6", "1999": "14,1", "2000": 14, "2001": "14,8", "2002": "15,1", "2003": "14,9", "2004": "15,5", "2005": "15,5", "2006": "15,8", "2007": "16,2", "2008": "16,1", "2009": "16,4", "2010": "17,6", "2011": "18,6", "2012": "18,4", "2013": "21,7", "2014": "25,1" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Europe", "Overall": "13,5", "1996": "11,2", "1997": "11,2", "1998": "11,3", "1999": "11,5", "2000": "11,5", "2001": "12,2", "2002": "12,3", "2003": "12,2", "2004": "12,5", "2005": "12,6", "2006": "12,8", "2007": 13, "2008": "12,6", "2009": "12,8", "2010": "13,4", "2011": "14,1", "2012": "13,7", "2013": "16,5", "2014": "21,4" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "J. Stefan Institute", "Overall": "13,3", "1996": "6,5", "1997": 8, "1998": "8,9", "1999": "9,7", "2000": 8, "2001": "10,6", "2002": 7, "2003": "8,2", "2004": 12, "2005": "9,5", "2006": "10,6", "2007": "13,4", "2008": "11,9", "2009": "12,8", "2010": "14,9", "2011": "15,5", "2012": "15,2", "2013": "19,7", "2014": "25,6" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Max Planck Society", "Overall": "30,3", "1996": "25,9", "1997": 24, "1998": "24,3", "1999": 25, "2000": "25,6", "2001": 27, "2002": "26,2", "2003": "27,6", "2004": "27,8", "2005": "27,8", "2006": "28,1", "2007": "29,4", "2008": "29,2", "2009": "30,9", "2010": "32,4", "2011": "33,2", "2012": "34,8", "2013": "39,8", "2014": "38,9" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "National Institute of Biology Ljubljana", "Overall": "17,7", "1996": 4, "1997": "13,3", "1998": 20, "1999": "13,3", "2000": "9,1", "2001": 15, "2002": "15,6", "2003": "20,8", "2004": "18,2", "2005": "14,7", "2006": "14,3", "2007": 18, "2008": "19,7", "2009": 20, "2010": "21,1", "2011": "16,7", "2012": "18,2", "2013": 19, "2014": "24,1" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "National Institute of Chemistry Ljubljana", "Overall": "21,5", "1996": "8,8", "1997": "4,1", "1998": "9,9", "1999": 15, "2000": "15,7", "2001": "21,4", "2002": "15,3", "2003": "18,4", "2004": "16,2", "2005": "20,4", "2006": "19,4", "2007": "30,8", "2008": "18,1", "2009": "19,4", "2010": "31,8", "2011": "23,1", "2012": "24,9", "2013": "29,3", "2014": 36 }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Scientific Research Centre of the Slovenian Academy of Sciences and Arts", "Overall": "5,9", "1996": 0, "1997": 0, "1998": 0, "1999": 0, "2000": 0, "2001": "NA", "2002": 0, "2003": 0, "2004": "14,3", "2005": "4,5", "2006": 0, "2007": 0, "2008": 0, "2009": "7,8", "2010": "2,4", "2011": "6,8", "2012": "4,8", "2013": 0, "2014": 30 }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Slovenia", "Overall": "10,7", "1996": "5,8", "1997": "5,7", "1998": "5,7", "1999": "6,8", "2000": "5,5", "2001": "6,5", "2002": "6,8", "2003": "7,6", "2004": "7,8", "2005": "8,5", "2006": "9,3", "2007": "10,7", "2008": "9,6", "2009": "9,7", "2010": "10,8", "2011": "11,8", "2012": "12,3", "2013": "15,4", "2014": "20,4" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "United States", "Overall": "18,3", "1996": "17,3", "1997": "17,5", "1998": "17,7", "1999": "17,7", "2000": "17,8", "2001": "18,9", "2002": "18,5", "2003": "17,7", "2004": "17,7", "2005": "17,3", "2006": "17,3", "2007": "17,6", "2008": "17,3", "2009": "17,4", "2010": "17,7", "2011": "18,4", "2012": "17,8", "2013": "20,2", "2014": 24 }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Universitat Stuttgart", "Overall": "12,9", "1996": "12,7", "1997": "10,5", "1998": "14,2", "1999": "13,8", "2000": "10,6", "2001": "11,5", "2002": "12,6", "2003": "10,3", "2004": "11,8", "2005": "9,7", "2006": "11,9", "2007": "11,2", "2008": "11,8", "2009": "11,9", "2010": "11,4", "2011": "13,7", "2012": "11,8", "2013": "16,4", "2014": "23,6" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "University of Ljubljana", "Overall": "10,9", "1996": "6,2", "1997": "6,1", "1998": "6,1", "1999": "7,1", "2000": 5, "2001": 6, "2002": "6,8", "2003": "8,9", "2004": "7,8", "2005": "8,8", "2006": "10,1", "2007": "11,3", "2008": "10,6", "2009": "10,2", "2010": "10,9", "2011": "12,1", "2012": "13,2", "2013": "14,6", "2014": "20,2" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "University of Maribor", "Overall": "9,5", "1996": "4,8", "1997": "3,6", "1998": "3,9", "1999": "1,9", "2000": "2,4", "2001": "2,4", "2002": "6,5", "2003": "4,5", "2004": "6,4", "2005": "8,8", "2006": "8,1", "2007": "9,4", "2008": 10, "2009": "8,5", "2010": "7,7", "2011": "9,9", "2012": 13, "2013": "15,9", "2014": "19,6" }, 
    { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "University of Nova Gorica", "Overall": "18,2", "1996": "NA", "1997": "NA", "1998": "NA", "1999": "8,3", "2000": 0, "2001": "4,2", "2002": 4, "2003": 10, "2004": "9,3", "2005": "12,3", "2006": 22, "2007": "25,2", "2008": "17,5", "2009": "12,2", "2010": "15,3", "2011": "15,9", "2012": "18,3", "2013": "25,6", "2014": "27,5" } 
  ], 
  "errors": [], "meta": { "delimiter": ";", "linebreak": "\r\n", "aborted": false, "truncated": false, "fields": [ "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)", "Overall", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014" ] }
};


// get the column of year 1996
var col1996 = parserOutput.data.map(
    function(value, index) {
        return value["1996"];  // dot notation would be possible here, if key wasn't a number
    }
);

// col1996 is now ["18,4", "13,3", "11,2", "6,5", ...]

// Some methods to output the result:
//alert(col1996);
//console.log(col1996);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = col1996.join('<br>');
```

```html
<p>Result in var col1996:</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: this just returns "TypeError: parserOutput.data.map is not a function"

should I be loading another external library and which one? I have jquery and papaParse for now

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič: It works perfectly for me. I have added a code snippet to my answer using your original data - see above. If parserOutput.data has no method .map then either data is not your original Array or your browser is old and not supporting the map method (available since ECMAscript 5).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// return object of year values as property of year
var yearData = $.map(data,function(value) {
  return $.map(value, function(years) {
    return Object.keys(years).filter(Number)
    .map(function(data) {
      var year = {};
      year[data] = years[data];
      return year
    })
  })
});

$("#graphcontainer").text(JSON.stringify(yearData, null, 2));

// filter year data
var filtered = function(year) {
  return [].slice.call(yearData).filter(function(years) {
    return Number(Object.keys(years)[0]) === year
  })
};
var year = filtered(1996);
```

```js
var data = data = { "data": [ { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "CNRS", "Overall": "22,6", "1996": "18,4", "1997": "18,6", "1998": "18,5", "1999": "17,3", "2000": "17,6", "2001": "18,6", "2002": "18,3", "2003": "17,5", "2004": "18,9", "2005": "20,2", "2006": "21,1", "2007": "22,1", "2008": "21,3", "2009": "22,9", "2010": "23,4", "2011": "25,3", "2012": "24,5", "2013": "29,3", "2014": "31,7" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "DACH - Austria, Germany and Switzerland", "Overall": "16,9", "1996": "13,3", "1997": "13,4", "1998": "13,6", "1999": "14,1", "2000": 14, "2001": "14,8", "2002": "15,1", "2003": "14,9", "2004": "15,5", "2005": "15,5", "2006": "15,8", "2007": "16,2", "2008": "16,1", "2009": "16,4", "2010": "17,6", "2011": "18,6", "2012": "18,4", "2013": "21,7", "2014": "25,1" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "Europe", "Overall": "13,5", "1996": "11,2", "1997": "11,2", "1998": "11,3", "1999": "11,5", "2000": "11,5", "2001": "12,2", "2002": "12,3", "2003": "12,2", "2004": "12,5", "2005": "12,6", "2006": "12,8", "2007": 13, "2008": "12,6", "2009": "12,8", "2010": "13,4", "2011": "14,1", "2012": "13,7", "2013": "16,5", "2014": "21,4" }, { "Output in top 10 percentiles (%)": "J. Stefan Institute", "Overall": "13,3", "1996": "6,5", "1997": 8, "1998": "8,9", "1999": "9,7", "2000": 8, "2001": "10,6", "2002": 7, "2003": "8,2", "2004": 12, "2005": "9,5", "2006": "10,6", "2007": "13,4", "2008": "11,9", "2009": "12,8", "2010": "14,9", "2011": "15,5", "2012": "15,2", "2013": "19,7", "2014": "25,6" } ] };

var yearData = $.map(data,function(value) {
  return $.map(value, function(years) {
    return Object.keys(years).filter(Number)
    .map(function(data) {
      var year = {};
      year[data] = years[data];
      return year
    })
  })
});

$("#graphcontainer").text(JSON.stringify(yearData, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="graphcontainer"></pre>
```